# How do I publish a port at run time of a Docker image on Amazon Ec2?

Tags: python, docker, amazon-ec2, portforwarding, docker-desktop

Currently, my `Docker` image runs as expected when run with the following line inside `VSCode's CLI`.

```
docker run -it -d -p 5000:5000 flaskapp
```

This allows me to open up `http://localhost:5000/` and access it. However, if I were to run it on Docker desktop, it does not allow me to access the localhost. Under my `Dockerfile`, I have made sure to include `EXPOSE 5000` inside.

```
docker build -t flaskapp:latest .
```

How do I run a `Docker` image inside `Docker desktop` or `EC2` with the `-p` flag?

Comment: I'm also using docker desktop, once the port is mounted to host you just can use with localhost.  When the time docker not support windows and used docker tool that time only this happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to specify host as 0.0.0.0 in the app.run().

Eg: app.run(host="0.0.0.0")

Then add an inbound rule in the ec2 instance security group to expose the port.

Use the ec2 instance IP with the port number to access it.